# Running multiple commands with su in Bash

Tags: bash, su

I would like to use `su -c` to run as root multiple commands altogether. I don't want to use an extra script for this.

I tried the following:

```
su root -c "tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC & " -c "ls -lh"
```

but it executes only the `ls` not the first one.

I tried the following:

```
su root -c "tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC & ; ls -lh;"
```

but it says that there is an error with the semicolon `;`.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This command runs fine:

```
su root -c "date; ls -lh"
```

But in this command:

```
su root -c "tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC & ; ls -lh;"
```

Since you have `&` before `;` therefore you are getting errors. Try removing `&` and re-executing the command.

Or you can run your command like this:

```
su root -c "(tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC &); ls -lh"
```

Comment: Of course, there’s no reason to add parentheses unless the OP really *really **really*** wants to type a `;` between the `tcpdump` and `ls` commands — just leave out the semicolons and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

As [anubhava says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10601/80216#10602), your

```
su root -c "tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC & ; ls -lh;"
```

command is failing because you’re not allowed to have
`&` followed immediately by `;`. 
You can see this just by typing the commands directly into the shell:

- `true & true`  works
- `true & ; true` doesn’t work

If you want the `tcpdump` command to run in the background,
remove the `;`, as in

```
su root -c "tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC & ls -lh;"
```

(and you don't need the `;` at the end, either, but it doesn’t hurt).

Answer (score 1):

I think the `nohup` command will get you what you want too... tcpdump running in the background (no ampersand necessary):

```
su root -c "nohup tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC ; ls -lh"
```

Comment: Hi I think so. NOHUP leaves commands running in background even when a user disconnect. I didn't remember that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: (1) It’s good to use `nohup` when you run commands in the background, but that really has nothing to do with this question.  (2) This answer is wrong — `nohup` by itself does not cause a command to run in the background; you still have to type `&` (which leaves us back where we started, with a syntax error in the command).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Anubhava's excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10602/201820):

You could use `{}` as well, like this:

```
su root -c "{ tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -w CCCCCC & }; ls -lh"
```

`{}` is a little more efficient than `()` in that it doesn't create a sub shell. `{}` does need a space after `{` and a `;` before `}` unless we have an `&` already.

Comment: Of course, there’s no reason to add braces or parentheses at all unless the user really *really **really*** wants to type a `;` between the `tcpdump` and `ls` commands — just leave out the semicolon and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use `&&` to separate your commands like so:

```
$ su -c "ls && ls"
```

Comment: Auch..that's my error. I wanted to run the process in background but I was not aware of this && to separate commands. Thx

Comment: && means "Only execute the second command if the first succeeded". If your first command errors out, the second one won't run. This is usually good, but I would hesitate to describe && as purely a separator.

Comment: And, if you want to run the ``tcpdump`` process in the background, ``&&`` does you no good whatsoever.